# .SUFFIXES refuses to work in Automake

Tags: makefile, automake

I have the following construct in my Makefile.am, which I need to port for use in Automake.

```
.SUFFIXES: .o .c .cpp
```

Now I tried using **'automake -a --foreign'** but that gives me the following error:

```
Makefile.am:73: error: use variable 'SUFFIXES', not target '.SUFFIXES'
```

If I change the Makefile.am to look like:

```
SUFFIXES: .o .c .cpp
```

Then automake runs successfully, but on running **"make"**, I get:

```
 cd . && /bin/bash ./config.status Makefile 
config.status: creating Makefile
(CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && )
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `(CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && )'
make: *** [config.h.in] Error 1
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated, as there's not much to go about it online. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using incorrect syntax for [SUFFIXES](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Suffixes.html)

```
SUFFIXES = .o .c .cpp
```

`automake` probably knows about those suffixes already, so without more context, it's hard to say if you really need `SUFFIXES` or not.